# loop function until limit is meet postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a pretty large table where i want to start from the lowest id and loop through and filter until i get 1000 rows which i then want to return.

So my function getFilteredItems will do some filtering and then return 1000 rows. It has a parameter of latestItemId so that it will take 1000 rows after a specific id. getFilteredItems is then called by getJournalistTopicItems that filteres even more. Most of the time this function will filter away all rows hence i want to loop through untill i eventually get 1000 rows when all the filtering is done.

I am super-noob at sql and specifically postgres so all this might been overkill or totaly wrong but this is what i've done so far.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getJournalistTopicItems() RETURNS  TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
    currentCount INTEGER = 0;
    currentItemIds int[];
    latestItem INTEGER = 0;
BEGIN       
        WHILE currentCount < 1000 LOOP      
            WITH fItems AS (
                SELECT * FROM getFilteredItems(latestItem)
            )
            SELECT fi.itemId, ift.content
            FROM fItems fi
            INNER JOIN journalistitems ji ON ji.itemid = fi.itemid       
            INNER JOIN itemfulltexts ift ON ji.itemid = ift.itemid
            INNER JOIN journalists j ON j.id = ji.journalistid
            INNER JOIN contacts c ON c.journalistid = j.id
              WHERE  c.isprivate = FALSE
              AND c.disabled = FALSE
              AND c.verificationstatus = 1;           

            currentItemIds := array_append(fi.itemId);
            currentCount := array_length(currentItemIds);
            SELECT latestItemId INTO latestItem FROM getFilteredItems(latestItem) limit 1;

        END LOOP;
        RETURN array_to_string(currentItemIds);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The function getFilteredItems looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getFilteredItems(latestId INTEGER) RETURNS TABLE(
    latestItemId integer,
    itemid integer
) AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    WITH fItems AS(select i.id 
        from items i
        inner join articlemetadatas am on am.itemid = i.id
        where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM journalistitemcategories jic WHERE jic.itemid = i.id)
          AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM topicitemwords tw WHERE tw.itemid = i.id)
          AND i.languagecode in ('sv')
          AND am.contentprotected != 0
          AND i.id > latestId
         limit 1000)
         SELECT (SELECT id FROM fItems order by id desc limit 1), fItems.id FROM fItems;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error i get when calling getJournalistTopicItems is this:

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function getjournalisttopicitems() line 8 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601
```

LATEST UPDATE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getJournalistTopicItems() RETURNS  SETOF TEXT AS $func$
DECLARE
    idarr int[];
    idmed int[];
    latestItem INTEGER = 0;
    currentCount INTEGER = 0;
BEGIN       
        WHILE currentCount < 1000 LOOP      
            WITH fItems AS (
                SELECT * FROM getFilteredItems(latestItem)
            )
            SELECT fi.itemId, ift.content
            FROM fItems fi
            INNER JOIN journalistitems ji ON ji.itemid = fi.itemid       
            INNER JOIN itemfulltexts ift ON ji.itemid = ift.itemid
            INNER JOIN journalists j ON j.id = ji.journalistid
            INNER JOIN contacts c ON c.journalistid = j.id
              WHERE  c.isprivate = FALSE
              AND c.disabled = FALSE
              AND c.verificationstatus = 1;           

            idmed := (select array_agg(itemId) from fItems);
            idarr := (select idarr || idmed);
            currentCount := (select array_length(currentCount, int));
            latestItem := (select latestItem FROM getFilteredItems(latestItem) limit 1);        

        END LOOP;
        RETURN QUERY SELECT array_to_string(idarr, ',');
END;
$func$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: could you maybe provide some sample data? Just a few lines..

Comment: @Humpelstielzchen to a specific table or to all of them?